# Armature bones created in python disappear after exiting edit mode

Tags: python, armature, import

I'm writing an importer for a file format with skeletal data, so I'd like to generate an armature with bones to represent it. I can put the object into edit mode and create EditBones without any trouble, but the bones then vanish as soon as I exit edit mode.

As far as I can tell, exiting Edit mode is supposed to convert EditBones to actual Bones, but that's not happening. Instead, when I exit Edit mode, the armature is reset back to the state it was in before I entered Edit mode.

Here's a test case that can be run line-by-line in Blender's Python console.

```
# Create a new armature, make it active, and put it into edit mode.
bpy.ops.object.armature_add( enter_editmode=True )

# Add a new bone named "test"
C.object.data.edit_bones.new( "test" )

# At this point, you can see the armature object with two bones ("Bone" and "test") in the Outliner

# Exit Edit mode by switching back to Object mode.
bpy.ops.object.mode_set( mode='OBJECT' )

# Result: the "test" bone vanishes without a trace.
```

I've tried a bunch of variations, all with the same end result. It feels like I'm missing a step; perhaps something to explicitly apply the edits.

I'm using Blender 2.68a and Blender 2.69.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the point of creation, the new bone's [`head`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_8/bpy.types.EditBone.html#bpy.types.EditBone.head) and [`tail`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_8/bpy.types.EditBone.html#bpy.types.EditBone.tail) is both `(0, 0, 0)`, which gives zero (invalid) length. You only need to modify at least one of them, giving a valid length, to keep the new bone outside of Edit mode:

```
>>> bone = C.object.data.edit_bones.new("test")
>>> bone.head = (0, 1, 0)
>>> bone.tail = (1, 1, 0)
>>> bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
# The new bone won't disappear after exiting edit mode.
```

Comment: I have the same problem but I want to use a matrix, how do I do that?