# Blender armature edit_bones changes aren't kept after switch to object mode

Tags: armature, edit-mode

I have some code that needs to add bones to an armature. I'm in edit mode. I add the bones using the_armature.data.edit_bones.new(). But when I leave edit mode the new bones I've added aren't there.

```
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT', toggle=False)
    
    <add my bones>
        
    print(f"***All armature edit bones: " + str(list(arm_ob.data.edit_bones.keys())))
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT', toggle=False)
    print(f"***All armature '{arm_ob.name}' bones: " + str(list(arm_ob.data.bones.keys())))
```

The first print statement shows the bones I've added. The second, I think, should always produce the same list as the first, but it doesn't. Here's the output:

```
***All armature edit bones: ['Arm_ForeArm3_skin.R', 'Arm_Collarbone_skin.L', 'RibHelper.R', 'Spine1_skin', 'Arm_ShoulderFat_skin.R', 'Arm_UpperFat_skin.R', 'Leg_Calf_skin.L', 'Belly_skin', 'ButtFat_skin.R', 'Arm_UpperTwist2_skin.L', 'ButtFat_skin.L', 'Arm_ForeArm2_skin.R', 'Leg_Thigh_skin.L', 'Arm_UpperFat_skin.L', 'Breast_skin.R', 'Breast_skin.L', 'Neck_Low_skin', 'Leg_Calf_Low_skin.L', 'Spine1_Rear_skin', 'Spine2_skin', 'Leg_Thigh_Fat_skin.R', 'Chest', 'UpperBelly_skin', 'Leg_Calf_skin.R', 'Chest_Upper_skin', 'Arm_Hand.L', 'Pelvis_Rear_skin', 'Chest_skin', 'Leg_Toe1.R', 'Leg_Toe1.L', 'Leg_Thigh_Low_skin.R', 'Arm_UpperArm_skin.L', 'Arm_UpperTwist2_skin.R', 'Arm_ShoulderFat_skin.L', 'Arm_UpperArm_skin.R', 'Leg_Thigh_skin.R', 'Arm_Collarbone.R', 'Neck_skin', 'Pelvis_skin', 'Arm_ForeArm1_skin.R', 'SPINE2', 'LArm_UpperTwist1_skin', 'Arm_ForeArm1_skin.L', 'Arm_Collarbone_skin.R', 'Arm_Collarbone.L', 'Arm_ForeArm2_skin.L', 'RibHelper.L', 'RArm_UpperTwist1_skin', 'Leg_Calf_Low_skin.R', 'Leg_Thigh_Low_skin.L', 'Chest_Rear_Skin', 'SPINE1', 'Spine2_Rear_skin', 'Leg_Foot.R', 'Leg_Foot.L', 'Arm_Hand.R', 'Arm_ForeArm3_skin.L', 'Leg_Thigh_Fat_skin.L', 'Arm_ForeArm3.R', 'Arm_UpperTwist2.R', 'Leg_Calf.L', 'Pelvis', 'Arm_UpperTwist2.L', 'Arm_ForeArm2.R', 'Leg_Thigh.L', 'Leg_Thigh.R', 'Leg_Calf.R', 'Arm_ForeArm3.L', 'Arm_UpperArm.L', 'Arm_UpperArm.R', 'Neck', 'Arm_ForeArm1.R', 'Arm_UpperTwist1.L', 'Arm_ForeArm1.L', 'Arm_ForeArm2.L', 'Arm_UpperTwist1.R', 'COM']
***All armature 'BASE meshes\Actors\Character\CharacterAssets\MaleBody.nif' bones: ['Leg_Calf_skin.L', 'ButtFat_skin.R', 'ButtFat_skin.L', 'Leg_Thigh_skin.L', 'Leg_Calf_Low_skin.L', 'Leg_Thigh_Fat_skin.R', 'Leg_Calf_skin.R', 'Pelvis_Rear_skin', 'Leg_Thigh_Low_skin.R', 'Leg_Thigh_skin.R', 'Pelvis_skin', 'Leg_Calf_Low_skin.R', 'Leg_Thigh_Low_skin.L', 'SPINE1', 'Spine1_skin', 'Belly_skin', 'Spine1_Rear_skin', 'SPINE2', 'Spine2_skin', 'Chest', 'RibHelper.R', 'Breast_skin.R', 'Breast_skin.L', 'Neck_Low_skin', 'Chest_Upper_skin', 'Chest_skin', 'Arm_Collarbone.R', 'Arm_ForeArm3_skin.R', 'Arm_ShoulderFat_skin.R', 'Arm_UpperFat_skin.R', 'Arm_ForeArm2_skin.R', 'Arm_UpperTwist2_skin.R', 'Arm_UpperArm_skin.R', 'Arm_ForeArm1_skin.R', 'Arm_Collarbone_skin.R', 'RArm_UpperTwist1_skin', 'Arm_Hand.R', 'Neck_skin', 'Arm_Collarbone.L', 'Arm_Collarbone_skin.L', 'Arm_UpperTwist2_skin.L', 'Arm_UpperFat_skin.L', 'Arm_Hand.L', 'Arm_UpperArm_skin.L', 'Arm_ShoulderFat_skin.L', 'LArm_UpperTwist1_skin', 'Arm_ForeArm1_skin.L', 'Arm_ForeArm2_skin.L', 'Arm_ForeArm3_skin.L', 'RibHelper.L', 'Chest_Rear_Skin', 'UpperBelly_skin', 'Spine2_Rear_skin', 'Leg_Foot.R', 'Leg_Toe1.R', 'Leg_Foot.L', 'Leg_Toe1.L', 'Leg_Thigh_Fat_skin.L']
```

How is this even possible?

Comment: Oops, might be a dup of: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6040/armature-bones-created-in-python-disappear-after-exiting-edit-mode?rq=1

Comment: Yes, it's a dup. I'm not sure how to delete or mark this one.