# Create and move bones using BoneList (BoneCollection) python

Tags: python, rigging, bones, collections

I try create script for my self to rigging. I create adn snap bones using this code for all bones(copy and paste)

```
RIG.data.edit_bones.new("RemRoll_bone1.L")
RIG.data.edit_bones['RemRoll_bone1.L'].head = RIG.data.edit_bones['bone1.L'].head
RIG.data.edit_bones['RemRoll_bone1.L'].tail = RIG.data.edit_bones['bone1.L'].tail
RIG.data.edit_bones['RemRoll_bone1.L'].roll = RIG.data.edit_bones['bone1.L'].roll

RIG.data.edit_bones.new("RemRoll_bone2.L")
RIG.data.edit_bones['RemRoll_bone2.L'].head = RIG.data.edit_bones['bone2.L'].head
RIG.data.edit_bones['RemRoll_bone2.L'].tail = RIG.data.edit_bones['bone2.L'].tail
RIG.data.edit_bones['RemRoll_bone2.L'].roll = RIG.data.edit_bones['bone1.L'].roll
```

I want do someting like this now, but im to new at the Scripting(

```
remroll_list = [

("bone1.L"),
("bone2.L")

]

for n1 in remroll_list:

    RIG.data.edit_bones.new.['RemRoll_'] + (n1)
    RIG.data.edit_bones['RemRoll_'] + (n1).head = RIG.data.edit_bones(n1).head
    RIG.data.edit_bones['RemRoll_'] + (n1).tail = RIG.data.edit_bones(n1).tail
    RIG.data.edit_bones['RemRoll_'] + (n1).roll = RIG.data.edit_bones(n1).roll
```

And I don't even know if it is possible to create and move with bones through the list.
hlp pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. This was easy!

```
import bpy

namelist = [

("Bone"),
("Bone.001"),
("Bone.002"),
("Bone.003")

]

for name123 in namelist:

    RIG = bpy.data.objects['Armature']

    RIG.data.edit_bones.new(('RemRoll_') + name123)
    RIG.data.edit_bones[('RemRoll_') + name123].head = RIG.data.edit_bones.get(name123).head
    RIG.data.edit_bones[('RemRoll_') + name123].tail = RIG.data.edit_bones.get(name123).tail
    RIG.data.edit_bones[('RemRoll_') + name123].roll = RIG.data.edit_bones.get(name123).roll
```

Comment: Note: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6040/armature-bones-created-in-python-disappear-after-exiting-edit-mode